# Not allowed to load local resource PHP Xampp

Tags: php, css, xampp

I am trying make bootstrap.php file that gets called everytime before i open a file, like my css. And i do this since i use the header in every page i need to have all of the links working without having to do multiple header depending on where in my folder structure i am. And this is the error:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP/assets/css/bootstrap.css

And here is my file structure.

[image]

#### index.php

```html
include ('bootstrap.php');
include (FOLDER_MAIN_HTML.'header.php');
```

#### bootstrap.php

```
define ('FOLDER_ROOT', 'C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP/');
define ('FOLDER_CSS', FOLDER_ROOT.'assets/css/');
```

#### header.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo FOLDER_CSS;?>bootstrap.css">
```

#### Dont know if its neccesarry but this is my httpd.conf in xampp

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP">
```

So thats what i have but it doesent work. Even when when i switch the root folder to `__DIR__` it still says no allowed. So do i need a htaccess file, and if so how do i do that? Or is there some other way.
And yes i have searched everywhere for a fix, and the code i have right now is from another post, from here.

Comment: you can add your css file path like this : `<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css">`

Comment: Is `FOLDER_ROOT` set somewhere? What does it contain? This should be the domain of your server (`http://localhost:8000/`), _not_ a path (`C:/xampp/htdocs/PHP/`)

Comment: I have now edited show my folder root. And i cant change the document root nor directory to (http://localhost:8000/). Since apache wont start if i do. kerbholz Also i know i can use the path like you have Sunil, but i run in to problems when i add the store section. So is there something else i can do to get this to work?